# Polynomial approximation

Tags: numerical-analysis, statistics, regression, polynomials

Is there any universal method to fill this matrix for any $n$ value:

$\textbf{A} = \left[ \matrix{n & \sum x_i & \sum x_i^2  & \cdots & \sum x_i^n \cr
             \sum x_i & \sum x_i^2 & \sum x_i^3 & \cdots & \sum x_i^{n+1} \cr
              \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr
              \sum x_i^n & \sum x_i^{n+1} & \sum x_i^{n+2} &\cdots & \sum x_i^{n+n}} \right]$

Or maybe, it is easier to carry out with Vandermonde matrix to calculate the polynomial coefficients?

I would be grateful for any suggestions and Fortran code.

Comment: Are you hoping for something other than `for` loops? Use a loop to compute the first row then use another loop to compute the rest of the rows by copying values from the row above and then compute the last value in the row.

Comment: Is $A(2,1)$ wrong? It should be $\sum{x_i}$, instead of $\sum{x^n_i}$, right ?

Comment: Right, my bad. Corrected.

Comment: @DougLipinski My intention is to find out how can I fill this matrix for any `n` degree, because I can not imagine any universal algorythm for that - only for particular degree, not any. I have calculated polynomial coefficients using the Vandermonde matrix and appended it with `y` data values  and then I have used Gauss elimination. But I would also like to know how can I do it using another method or to know, whether it is not efficient.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Why will loops not work for "any `n`"? Just use n to define your loop limits. Here's a fully functional solution for MATLAB (just define `n` and `x` first): `A = zeros(n+1); for j=0:n, A(1,j+1)=sum(x.^j); end, for i=1:n, A(i+1,1:n)=A(i,2:n+1); A(i+1,n+1)=sum(x.^(n+i)); end`

Comment: Thank You so much! I just did not how to make those loops. Really helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this with for loops. Just use `n` to define your loop limits. Here's a fully functional solution for MATLAB (just define n and x first):

```
%pre-allocate A
A = zeros(n+1);

%first row:
for j=0:n
    A(1,j+1)=sum(x.^j);
end

%rows 2 through n
for i=1:n
    A(i+1,1:n)=A(i,2:n+1); %copy from previous row
    A(i+1,n+1)=sum(x.^(n+i)); %compute last entry in row
end
```

This method requires `(2*n+1)*(2*numel(x))` operations so if `x` has about `n` values the method is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

Answer (score 8):

$\mathbf{A}$ is an $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix. It can be obtained as follows:

$\textbf{A} = \left[ \matrix{1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \cr
              x_0 & x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_{n} \cr
              \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \cr
              x_0^n & x_1^n & x_2^n & \cdots & x_n^{n}}\right] \left[ \matrix{1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^n \cr
              1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n} \cr
              \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \cr
              1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_i^{n}}\right] $

Note that the decomposition doesn't involve any summation and can be easily computed using simple indexing and power operations. The matrix multiplication is an effective operator to compute the final matrix $\mathbf{A}$. This is both efficient and easy to implement.

The matrix on the right is simply a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) with an added column (right-most). Here is a MATLAB 2-liner to implement this:

```
% x is the input column vector, n is the number of elements e.g. n=length(x)
W = [ fliplr(vander(x)) (x.^n)];
A = W'*W;
```

This should work faster than for-looping in MATLAB since `vander` function doesn't contain any loops. It is also definitely shorter and cleaner.

I believe that making a quick remark is important here. Unlike common belief, when properly implemented matrix multiplication is not $O(N^3)$, but $<O(N^{2.4})$. Many available packages are already very optimized. Using vector instruction sets, along with parallelization brings further speed-up. However, the theoretical complexity never comes to $O(N^2)$ which is achieved via for-looping. This approach is only neater and faster in MATLAB for small sized matrices (up to ~ N<1500).

Also note that, even if the matrix notation is used here, the multiplication could still benefit from the special structure of these matrices. If one is to utilize this property, similar complexity can be obtained.

Comment: Depending on what OP needs to do with this matrix, they may be better off just leaving it in this form. I.e. if the need to form matrix-vector products, they're better off not forming $A$ at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can do it using Vandermonde matrix and then using Gauss elimination, or even simplier inverse matrices method, but my intention is to know how to fill this specified array I have written in the post or to know whether it is not efficient and the Vandermonde one is better to use.

Comment: This matrix multiplication takes $O(n^3)$ time, but the matrix as originally written takes $O(n^2)$ to evaluate (there are $2n$ distinct components, each taking $O(n)$ time). Isn't this form *more* expensive?

Comment: It might be more efficient for certain software (e.g. MATLAB), which requires for-less implementations. Both matrices can be formed in a vectorized fashion and multiplication is done through BLAS, which is already optimized.

Comment: @TolgaBirdal For large enough $n$ that wouldn't work and an $O(n^2)$ algorithm would be faster than an $O(n^3)$ algorithm.

Comment: You're making some claims about performance of your method in Matlab that aren't quite true. For `numel(x)=n=5000` this method is 4x slower for me (than the one in my answer) and it only gets worse for larger n (e.g. ~8x slower for n=10000, ~16x for 20000, etc). They are comparable for small n, but this method is $O(n^3)$ so as Kirill said it *will* be more expensive for large n. On my machine it takes longer for any case where the run time is longer than about 1 second and a difference of 200 s vs. 20 s feels a lot worse than a difference of 0.01 s or 0.05 s.

Comment: Dear Doug, some performance on my machine:
tic(); W = [ fliplr(vander( [x] ) ) ((x').^length(x))]  ; A=W'*W; toc();
Elapsed time is 0.000317 seconds.
Your code: Elapsed time is 0.084542 seconds. x=5000 is already very large, as it exhausts the memory for polynomial fitting. (i.e. Solving the system gets expensive). I usually target small numbers. Nevertheless, for n=5000, my code: Elapsed time is 7.360406 seconds. Your code: Elapsed time is 13.358014 seconds. This is on MATLAB 2015. This is predictable, since the loops are pretty slow compared to BLAS operations in MATLAB.

Comment: Well then I would say this is highly architecture and problem size dependent. I just tested on another machine (Macbook Air, Matlab 2014b) with n=5000 and got timings of 108.167382 (`vander` method) and 3.831718 (`for` loops method). For n=10000 I get 1172.083868 and 12.172999. Clearly an $O(n^2)$ method will win for large n, but how large n needs to be depends on the platform.

Comment: Okay, I have run the tests on 2 other computers, including a Macbook Air. It seems that before n~1500, vectorized code outperforms. They seem to equate around that point. Then for-loops start to beat.  My $x$ is a uniformly distributed random vector.